# Can the existence of multiplicative inverse of real numbers be derived from its other properties?

Tags: real-numbers, rational-numbers

Is there a construction of some subset of real numbers where the existence of multiplicative inverse of real numbers be derived by its other properties?

In particular, I am curious of the following more limited question: consider the set of limits of all convergent rational sequences $S$. For every $x\in S$, are we guaranteed to find a sequence in $S$ whose limit is the multiplicative inverse of $x$? (Where multiplication is defined via constructing rationals as equivalent classes of ordered pairs of integers.)

Comment: Is $x$ a sequence or a limit? Is $S$ a set of limits or a set of converging sequences?  Remember that $0$ does not have a multiplicative inverse.

Comment: If you have a Cauchy converging sequence of rationals, where the sequence does not contain $0$ and does not have a limit of $0$, then the sequence formed by multiplicative inverses is also a Cauchy converging sequence

Comment: Limit. $S$ is a set of limits. Why is the Cauchy converging statement true please?

Comment: If all the tail values of a sequence are between $q_1$ and $q_2$ (same sign) so differ by less than $|q_1-q_2|$ then all their reciprocals are between $q_1^{-1}$ and $q_2^{-1}$ which differ by less than $\frac{|q_1-q_2|}{\min(|q_1|,|q_2|)^2}$ so the gap on the reciprocals can be made arbitrarily small

Comment: Suppose $x_n\in\mathbb{Q}$ is a Cauchy sequence with $x_n\neq 0$ for all $n$ and $x_n\not\to 0$.  From $x_n\not\to 0$, we have $[-\frac1m,\frac1m]\cap\{x_n\mid n\in\mathbb{N}\}=\varnothing$ for large enough $m\in\mathbb{N}$.  Hence $\lvert \frac1{x_n}-\frac1{x_{n'}}\rvert=\frac{\lvert x_n-x_{n'}\rvert}{\lvert x_nx_{n'}\rvert}\leq m^2\lvert x_n-x_{n'}\rvert$ for all $n,n'$ so $1/x_n$ is Cauchy.